# How to set ~port /dev/ttyusb? parameter in arbotix python?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Referenc; http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix_python?distro=groovy, 2. Driver Node, 2.1.4 Parameters

Have a Trossen Turtlebot Arm driven by an Arbotix controller & want to run arbotix_gui or arbotix_terminal at the same time as a create turtlebot & need to set the arbotix_gui to use /dev/ttyusb1 to interface with the Arbotix controller usb cable, as the turtlebot uses /ttyusb0, apart from hard coding the arbotix_gui python script. The 2.3 Configuration text describes using an YAML file to set parameters and a launch file: but in what directories do the launch and default.yaml files go? Any easy way to set the arbotix default port to /dev/ttyusb1? I realize that a necessary procedure is to plug turtlebot usb cable in first, launch it, then plug in the arbotix cable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143296/how-to-set-%7Eport-/dev/ttyusb?-parameter-in-arbotix-python?/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running the command from the command line you can do add `_port:=/dev/ttyX` to the command to change the port.  The launch files can be kept in a new package that depends on the packages you are calling.  You may want to create udev rules for the devices.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2014-03-26**:
Tnx. May I ask what specific "command to change the port" do I add the _port string in your comment? Also the launch question, the package is "arbotix_python", so  in what folder would my new launch folder and file go?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-03-26**:
Try 'rosrun arbotix_python arbotix_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB1', I don't have a board to test with.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-03-26**:
Did you compile the package from source or install from debs?  If you installed it from the debs, you need to make a new package in a workspace that depends on arbotix and I'd recommend that even if you installed it from source.  If it was installed from source, you can just make a launch folder.